# Is there a shortcut in eclipse to display the current control flow?

Tags: eclipse, editor

I usually stumble upon complex business logic and get lost within the mist of the complex code. So I need to find were exactly I am in which I will go and see exactly which flow control, or branching, that led me in to the current statement. I remember JBuilder had a feature where it will give me a overlay over the editor showing exactly where I am, so does Eclipse have such feature?

Comment: @TDS Back ticks are not for adding emphasis. Please stop doing that, your edits are just making work for the rest of us who have to fix them.

Answer (score 0):

A more 'control flow'-centric solution (than my original answer below) would be:

[**Control Flow Graph Factory 3.7**](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/679)

> [image: icon] Control Flow Graph Factory is an Eclipse plugin which generates **control flow graphs from java bytecode**, edit them and export to GraphXML, DOT or several image formats.

[image: SourceCode Visualizer] [image: source code graph]

---

But on the static side, when coding, you can add the [Mylyn plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/) in order to isolate the specific context you want when exploring some code (see "[Task-Focused Interface](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Mylyn/User_Guide#Task-Focused_Interface) "):

[image: Focusing Navigator Views]

Without Mylyn, you have the [outline view](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/coutline.htm) which displays at least the function you are in:

[image: outline view]

---

On the runtime side, you have the Debug perspective which will display where you are in the code at any point of the Debug session.
See "[Java Debugging with Eclipse - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html) "

[image: eclipse debug view]

Comment: Thanx VonC but i doubt that this is the best solution within the Eclipse es. Hopefully I find a way to update this thread with

Comment: @user1412040 do you have a more precise illustration of what you saw with JBuilder?

Comment: @user1412040 was it about the code, or about a debug session?

Comment: @user1412040 ok I have added a plugin that could be closer to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a while ago this plugin for my thesis. http://eclipsefcg.sourceforge.net/